# Passing argument to KSH script with spaces

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I have a need to pass string of words to a KSH script as follows

```
  $ script.sh -p "a b c"
```

I am expecting to see the following

```
  PARMS a b c
```

But when I try to print out the value of $PARMS, only the first word word that is "a" prints out

```
    #!/bin/ksh

    ARGS=`getopt p: $*`

    set -- $ARGS

    for i
    do
       case "$i"
       in
        -p)     PARMS=$2; shift; shift;;
        --)     shift; break;;
    esac
    done

    echo "PARMS" "${PARMS}"
```

Comment: What version of `getopt` are you using? The BSD version simply notes that handling arguments with whitespace is buggy, while the GNU version attempts to provide a fix that isn't compatible with other versions of `getopt`.

Comment: Since you aren't using a long option, you may want to consider using the POSIX `getopts` command instead.

Comment: **Always** use `"$@"` instead of `$*` when you want to refer to the list of arguments with boundaries intact, and **never** try to store a list in a string (only variables can do that safely!).

Comment: (ergh, should have been "only *array* variables can do that safely!")

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of getopts usage in ksh.

```
#!/bin/ksh

DEFAULT_SITE_NAME="a.b.c.d"

SITE_NAME=$DEFAULT_SITE_NAME

USAGE="[-author?Andre Gelinas]"
USAGE+="[-copyright?2020]"
USAGE+="[+NAME?getopts.sh --- Example of getopts]"
USAGE+="[+DESCRIPTION?Example of getopts usage in ksh.]"
USAGE+="[s:site]:?[site:=$DEFAULT_SITE_NAME?Site name.]"
USAGE+="[p:param]:[param?Parameters to test.]"
USAGE+=$'[+SEE ALSO?\aMAN Page\a(1)]'

while getopts "$USAGE" optchar ; do
    case $optchar in
    p)  PARAM_TO_PRINT=$OPTARG ;;
    s)  SITE_NAME=$OPTARG ;;
    esac
done

print "Paramters [p] : "$PARAM_TO_PRINT
print "Site [s] : "$SITE_NAME
```

It supports short (-p) and long (--param=) type of option. The -s is there only as an example of optional option with default value.
It supports also --help and --man for the usage.

Example :

```
$ ./getopts.sh --param="a b c" --site=t.t.t.t
Paramters [p] : a b c
Site [s] : t.t.t.t
$ ./getopts.sh -p "a b c"
Paramters [p] : a b c
Site [s] : a.b.c.d
```